# golang grpc stubs, omit non empty values on marshalling

Tags: go, grpc, grpc-go

so I have this fields on my struct (autogenerated)

```
Id string `protobuf:"bytes,1,opt,name=id,proto3" json:"-"`
Name string `protobuf:"bytes,2,opt,name=name,proto3" json:"name,omitempty"`
```

Skipping fields if json marshal is super easy, you just set it to `-`

Is there a way to do a similar trick with grpc? Don't want to output all fields, also don't want to manually nullify some of the fields on the object, even though it's possible

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "output" in this context? Are you asking for a way to selectively exclude a field when running `proto.Marshal` without changing the `struct` instance? (if so I don't think the package provides that functionality).

Comment: Yes, selectively exclude fields with proto.Marshal